# optimizing markov chain transition matrix calculations?

Tags: r, markov-chains

As an intermediate R user, I know that for loops can very often be optimized by using functions like `apply` or otherwise. However, I am not aware of functions that can optimize my current code to generate a markov chain matrix, which is running quite slowly. Have I max-ed out on speed or are there things that I am overlooking? I am trying to find the transition matrix for a Markov chain by counting the number of occurrences in 24-hour time periods before given alerts. The vector `ids` contains all possible id's (about 1700).

The original matrix looks like this, as an example:

```
>matrix
      id      time
       1     1376084071
       1     1376084937
       1     1376023439
       2     1376084320
       2     1372983476
       3     1374789234
       3     1370234809
```

And here is my code to try to handle this:

```
matrixtimesort <- matrix[order(-matrix$time),]
frequency = 86400 #number of seconds in 1 day

# Initialize matrix that will contain probabilities
transprobs <- matrix(data=0, nrow=length(ids), ncol=length(ids))

# Loop through each type of event
for (i in 1:length(ids)){
localmatrix <- matrix[matrix$id==ids[i],]

# Loop through each row of the event
for(j in 1:nrow(localmatrix)) {
    localtime <- localmatrix[j,]$time
    # Find top and bottom row number defining the 1-day window
    indices <- which(matrixtimesort$time < localtime & matrixtimesort$time >= (localtime - frequency))
    # Find IDs that occur within the 1-day window
    positiveids <- unique(matrixtimesort[c(min(indices):max(indices)),]$id)
    # Add one to each cell in the matrix that corresponds to the occurrence of an event

            for (l in 1:length(positiveids)){
            k <- which(ids==positiveids[l])
            transprobs[i,k] <- transprobs[i,k] + 1
            }
    }

# Divide each row by total number of occurrences to determine probabilities
transprobs[i,] <- transprobs[i,]/nrow(localmatrix)
    }
  # Normalize rows so that row sums are equal to 1
  normalized <- transprobs/rowSums(transprobs)
```

Can anyone make any suggestions to optimize this for speed?

Comment: A good place to start is to use `Rprof` to profile your code.  This will tell you where it is spending most of it's time.

Comment: This is false: "loops can very often be optimized by using functions like apply".

Comment: There is a CodeReview site that might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested loops seems a bad idea. Your code can be vectorized to speed up.

For example, why find the top and bottom of row numbers? You can simply compare the time value with "time_0 + frequency": it is a vectorized operation.

HTH.

Comment: The reason I found the top and bottom row of numbers is because this is a huge dataset (5 million rows), and testing whether each "time" value is within time_0 and time_0+frequency takes much longer (I tried timing this a few weeks ago).  It is a good suggestion though.